# Apache Http Client, HostnameVerifier

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using Apache Http Client 4.5.14 but I am struggling with error:

> Certificate for <sub1.sub2.sub3.domain.com> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [ *.sub3.domain.com, SAN2, SAN3]

After some digging I learned that this error is generated because wildcard * do not support multiple subdomains. HttpClientBuilder allow me to set custom SSLHostnameVerifier when default verifcations fails but I am missing somthing.

```
builder.setSSLContext(context); // SSLContext context with loaded trustStore.jks and keysotre.jks 

builder.setSSLHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {

   private boolean matchDomian(String hostname, String subjectAlternativeName ) {
     // return true if SAN checks agains hostname, allow first wildcard * to be multiple subdomain
   }
    @Override
     public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
          for(String subjectAlternativeName: subjectAlternativeNames) {
        if(matchDomian(hostname,subjectAlternativeName)) return true;
       }
       return false;
      }
});
```

But I don't get how I get this array of all SANS in my error.
`Certificate for <sub1.sub2.sub3.domain.com> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [ *.sub3.domain.com, SAN2, SAN3]`

I tried casting cert to X509Certificate and using
`Collection<List<?>> sans = cert.getSubjectAlternativeNames();`

but there was nothing in here. I checked with Keytool and yes in trustStore I don't have 2.5.29.17 .

Then how do I get Subject Alternative Names in error( yes they were correct) , and how can I access them ? Or can I configure some parameters to allow * to be multiple subdomains ?

Yes I know I can disable all checking via

```
builder.setSSLHostnameVerifier(NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE);
```

but this is not solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was casting to X509Certificate from TrusManagers[] created before. If I get X509Certificate from session.getPeerCertificates() there is value present in getSubjectAlternativeNames

```
public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
    X509Certificate[] peerCertificates = (X509Certificate[]) session.getPeerCertificates();
    for(X509Certificate peerCertificate:peerCertificates ) {

        Collection<List<?>> sans = peerCertificate.getSubjectAlternativeNames();

        
    }
    return false;
```